# Filter rows based upon 2 or more occurrences across columns in R

Tags: r

I am attempting to filter out rows in which there is an occurrence only in a single column, and show only those that appear in more than one.

An example database:

|  | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| row2 | 6 | 0 | 42 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| row3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| row4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 87 |

In this case, I would want my filter to only return row2 and row3. I have been attempting to use dplyr and the filter feature; although I haven't found a way to capture all 7 columns. I'm unable to use `rowSums()` since the actual value isn't important in this case, only the frequency alongside another column.

I have thus far only *accurately* captured the output I am looking for when exclusively comparing two columns for values >0:

```
mydata.df %>%
  filter(col1>0 & col2>0)
```

Though it's easy to see why this approach isn't feasible, especially with 7 columns to compare. I have tried stringing multiple conditions to compare amongst multiple columns without success. Short of writing a separate filter for each of the combinations of columns independently, I'm sure I am missing an obvious and simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `filter` with `rowSums`

```
library(dplyr)
mydata.df %>% 
   filter(rowSums(. > 0) >=2)
     col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
row2    6    0   42    0    0    0    0
row3    0    0    0    0    1    1    0
```

---

Or if it is pairwise combination of columns that we are checking

```
library(purrr)
mydata.df %>% 
    filter(combn(., 2, FUN = function(x) rowSums(x > 0) == 2, 
         simplify = FALSE) %>% 
      reduce(`|`))
     col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
row2    6    0   42    0    0    0    0
row3    0    0    0    0    1    1    0
```

#### data

```
mydata.df <- structure(list(col1 = c(1L, 6L, 0L, 0L), col2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), col3 = c(0L, 42L, 0L, 0L), col4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), col5 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L), col6 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), col7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 87L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("row1", "row2", "row3", 
"row4"))
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Looks like I gave up too soon in terms of `rowSums`. Counted it out since I viewed the actual row values as arbitrary, and my attempts resulted in >1 pulling rows with sums of just that.