# how to filter rows that have only 2 or more columns equal to 1?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 5 columns `x1` ... `x5`. All of them are dummy variables. I want to filter rows only when **2 or more** columns are equal to 1. For example, from `df`, only rows 1, 4 and 10 would be selected because:

- row 1, `x2` = 1, `x3` = 1, `x4` = 1
- row 4, `x1` = 1, `x3` = 1,
- row 10, `x2` = 1, `x5` = 1
- the remaining rows are filtered out because either none or only one column is equal to 1.

Is there a way to achieve this using `dplyr::filter`?

data:

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  x1 = sample(c(1,0), size = 10, replace = T, prob = c(0.2, 0.8)),
  x2 = sample(c(1,0), size = 10, replace = T, prob = c(0.2, 0.8)),
  x3 = sample(c(1,0), size = 10, replace = T, prob = c(0.2, 0.8)),
  x4 = sample(c(1,0), size = 10, replace = T, prob = c(0.2, 0.8)),
  x5 = sample(c(1,0), size = 10, replace = T, prob = c(0.2, 0.8))
)

> df
   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
1   0  1  1  1  0
2   0  0  0  1  0
3   0  0  0  0  0
4   1  0  1  0  0
5   1  0  0  0  0
6   0  1  0  0  0
7   0  0  0  0  0
8   1  0  0  0  0
9   0  0  0  0  0
10  0  1  0  0  1
```

What I want:

```
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
1  0  1  1  1  0
2  1  0  1  0  0
3  0  1  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for `dplyr::filter`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(rowSums(across(everything())) >= 2)

  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
1  0  1  1  1  0
2  1  0  1  0  0
3  0  1  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
> df[rowSums(df)>=2, ]
   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
1   0  1  1  1  0
4   1  0  1  0  0
10  0  1  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually just found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68537511/16421247) using `rowSums`...

```
df |> 
  mutate(row_sum = rowSums(x=df)) |> 
  filter(row_sum >= 2)

  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 row_sum
1  0  1  1  1  0       3
2  1  0  1  0  0       2
3  0  1  0  0  1       2
```